# Add Annotation into mapView with two function

Tags: swift, mapbox

I have created these two functions and when I call function pippo() I receive an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", in order to fix this error I have modified this `mapView.addAnnotation(hello)` into `mapView?.addAnnotation(hello)`, but I don't show the annotation into the map, if I call pippo inside caricamappa the annotation is successfully added, but I want to separate function load maps and add annotation, is it possible?

```
func caricamappa(){
    let styleURL = NSURL(string: "mapbox://**")
    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds,
                              styleURL: styleURL as URL?)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Set the map’s center coordinate and zoom level.
    mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 46.370417,
                                              longitude: 8.411713),
                      zoomLevel: 13, animated: false)
    view.addSubview(mapView)
    mapView.delegate = self

}

func pippo(){
    let hello = MGLPointAnnotation()
    hello.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 46.376362, longitude: 8.396907)
    hello.title = "Hello world!"
    hello.subtitle = "Welcome to my marker"

    // Add marker `hello` to the map.
    mapView.addAnnotation(hello)

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    caricamappa()
    pippo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define mapView in `caricamappa` so it doesn't exist in `pippo` Instead, make mapView an IBOutlet outside of your methods.

Comment: Ok thanks!! now i see the annotation , but i need to use function  func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
            if let point = annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation, and into pippo is not possible to use this function, right?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Could you add more code to your original post and I'll try to help.